# Python3: how convert string to "\x00...."

Tags: python, python-3.x

How to convert string `"Серия 1"` to string `"\x412\x437\x440\x44b\x432\x430\x44f"` for  write to file.

```
def create_playlist(playlist):
  gplaylist = "[playlist]\n"
  playlist1 = json.loads(playlist)
  x = 1;
  for i in enumerate(playlist1):
    for j in enumerate(i[1]['folder']):
      gplaylist += "File" + str(x) + "=" + parse_file(j[1]['file']) + "\n"
      # Variable: j[1]['title'] must converted to "\x412\x437\x440\x44b\x432\x430\x44f"
      gplaylist += "Title" + str(x) + "=" + j[1]['title'] + "\n"
      x += 1
  gplaylist += "NumberOfEntries=" + str(x-1)
  write_playlist(gplaylist)

def write_playlist(playlist):
   with io.open('play_list.pls', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as outfile:
      outfile.write(to_unicode(playlist))
```

Comment: I don't understand. How does `Серия 1` turn into `\x412\x437\x440\x44b\x432\x430\x44f`? What encoding is that? And why can't you just write the string `"Серия 1"` to the file?

Comment: Just store the file as UTF-8 and add the line `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` near the beginning of the file. This way you can just use all characters literally in string literals.

Comment: How to convert j[1]['title'].encode('iso-8859-5') to string? str(j[1]['title'].encode('iso-8859-5')) wite to file as " b'\xc1\xd5\xe0\xd8\xef 20<br/>\xc1\xd5\xd7\xde\xdd 4' ", but need " \xc1\xd5\xe0\xd8\xef 20<br/>\xc1\xd5\xd7\xde\xdd 4 "

Answer (score 0):

You should stop playing with encodings where it's not really necessary. Everything works perfectly as it is:

```
$ python
>>> with open('part1.txt', 'w') as fout :
...     fout.write( 'Серия 1\n' )
... 
>>> 
$ cat part1.txt
Серия 1
$
```